# What is the difference between tclsh85 executable and tclsh85s executable?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

What is the difference between tclsh85 executable and tclsh85s executable?
I can find the both executable in Tcl Directory
Thanks

Comment: They should be the same I think. I forgot why there are copies though.

Comment: The s version is usually statically linked, the normal one is dynamically linked.

Answer (score 2):

They're built from exactly the same source code, with almost identical options; they should be functionally indistinguishable to the enormous majority of scripts. The only difference is that `tclsh85s.exe` is statically linked to the Tcl library and its supporting libraries (only system libraries like `msvcrt.dll`), which is a little bit more awkward for updating (as well as being not so efficient) but quite a lot better for simple redistribution.

You shouldn't see any performance or functionality difference if you're not doing something that directly touches on the linking or redistribution of the code.